# libphonenumber PHP country

Tags: php, libphonenumber

I am using this library: https://github.com/davideme/libphonenumber-for-PHP. Here is the demo code:

```
<?php
use com\google\i18n\phonenumbers\PhoneNumberUtil;
use com\google\i18n\phonenumbers\PhoneNumberFormat;
use com\google\i18n\phonenumbers\NumberParseException;

require 'PhoneNumberUtil.php';

$swissNumberStr = "1212-894-3000";
$phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
try {
    $swissNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parseAndKeepRawInput($swissNumberStr, "US");

    echo $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat::E164) . PHP_EOL;


echo $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat::INTERNATIONAL) . PHP_EOL;
echo $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL) . PHP_EOL;
echo $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat::E164) . PHP_EOL;

echo $phoneUtil->formatOutOfCountryCallingNumber($swissNumberProto, "US") . PHP_EOL;    
} catch (NumberParseException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Error type: 0. Missing or invalid default region.
```

Codes for Pakistan and other countries work but `"US"`, `"Canada"`, `"UK"`, etc, are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a bug in the code. I have fixed it. The bug is in PhoneNumberUtil.php. The function name

```
private function init($filePrefix) {
```

at line number 231 is searching for a key called REGION_CODE_FOR_NON_GEO_ENTITY which is equal to "001" defined online 119. As there is no key matching "001" in the array it unsets 0th element which "US". I have fixed the bug and I will report to the developer on GitHub. The new function is as follows.

```
private function init($filePrefix) {
    $this->currentFilePrefix = dirname(__FILE__) . '/data/' . $filePrefix;
    foreach ($this->countryCallingCodeToRegionCodeMap as $regionCodes) {
        $this->supportedRegions = array_merge($this->supportedRegions, $regionCodes);
    }
    $nongeoentity=array_search(self::REGION_CODE_FOR_NON_GEO_ENTITY, $this->supportedRegions);
    if($nongeoentity)
    unset($this->supportedRegions[array_search(self::REGION_CODE_FOR_NON_GEO_ENTITY, $this->supportedRegions)]);
    $this->nanpaRegions = $this->countryCallingCodeToRegionCodeMap[self::NANPA_COUNTRY_CODE];
}
```

Comment: Thanks You so much. now when i enter this $swissNumberStr = "43 0 50108-10000"; and country = "AT" . it is showing me the same result. it is not formatting the number.Output = +43 4305010810000 . 
but when i enter this number in input= "0 50108-10000" (remove country code) then it replies with correct : +43 50 1081 0000